# How to show multiple 'clones' of a custom NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow

I want to do something like the "New" on the TextEdit app. 
Every time you press cmd+n or you click on "New" a new window appears and you can do this multiple times.
How to achieve something like this? I've tried using `NSWindowController` but I can only show 1 Window at a time when i call `[windowController showWindow:nil];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though what you are trying to build is a document-based application (which will automatically manage a window for each open document).

Read Apple's [Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html) for details.

Comment: but the thing is, my app doesn't create documents or anything like that. let's say the user takes 5 pictures, the app will open 5 windows with 1 image in each window for the user to edit colors, etc (it's just an example). So, should I still go with document-based app?

Comment: Yes. From what you're describing, it's likely that each of the pictures open in your application can usefully be treated as a document.